# NSMutableURLRequest setValue

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, http-post

What does setValue when making an HTTP POST do, I am making a POST to my py script and it only works if in my request I have

```
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postString length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-length"];
```

And then in my py script at the beginning I have

```
print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n"
```

Why what does this do?

Thanks

Comment: it is the content type by which the receiver can come to know which type data he is going to receive. if the data is an image or video it has different content type. and for plain text its different.

Comment: @GauravParmar is there a way where I can not have the print statement in my py script?

Comment: i am not able to understand what did you mean. Can you please explain your problem and wht do you want to do ?

Comment: @GauravParmar I am wondering if there is something else I could replace this line with `print "Content-type: text/plain\n\n"` as print things comes back in the response.

Comment: how can it come back in resposne.?

Comment: @GauravParmar I don't want it to come back in the response

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82449/discussion-between-gaurav-parmar-and-spenf10).